# How can I use Trello on a touchscreen (Elo - Windows 7 or 8, any browser)?

Tags: trello

I can't drag items with my fingers (can be done only with a mouse).

Answer (score 2):

Dragging isn't possible on touch devices at the moment. To move cards, you can click the menu button in the top right corner and select "Move...". Not ideal, but it works.